# includeOpForFullLoad property on Parquet files - AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, aws-dms

I have tried includeOpForFullLoad property for csv files while reading from oracle and writing in to s3. I wanted to use this property for parquet files. I can see it works for Incremental but not on full load. Anyone tried ? ?

Answer (score 1):

IncludeOpForFullLoad is available to CSV only. but there's a workaround way to overcome this limitation by using DMS transformational rule

```
 - rule-type: transformation
  rule-id: 20021
  rule-name: 20021
  rule-action: add-column
  rule-target: column
  object-locator:
    schema-name: {{ SchemaName }}
    table-name: "{{ TableName }}"
  value: op
  expression: "'I'"
  data-type:
    type: string
    length: 10
```